# не показывает график plotly

Tags: python, визуализация, plotly

```
import chart_studio.plotly
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace = go.Scatter(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [3, 1, 6])
fig = go.Figure(data=trace)

iplot(fig,show_link=False)
```

Этот блок выполяется и созатеся ниже блок из пустого полотна, самого графика нет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите документацию https://plotly.com/python/  у вас нехватает fig.show()

Comment: @Интик вместо него у меня вроде как iplot, но даже если show() то все равно не выводит